# How can i reuse a variable more efficiently in cakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have the code:

```
        $getCookieData = $this->Cookie->read('data');
    $getUser = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $getCookieData['username'])));
```

Basically I'm using this in a lot of locations to get the users information and either show it, compare it, etc. I was just wondering if there was a more efficient way for me to use the variable all around my site, instead of repeating myself a lot.

Comment: Why not use sessions instead of reading cookie data?

Comment: You think sessions are more appropriate?

Comment: @SamPerrin: Seesion have a time limit once expired, your data wont be available unless you recreate it and store your data again

Comment: @Blaster i might think about changing to sessions. Thanks.

Comment: @SamPerrin so you're saying cookie data doesn't have a time limit and expire? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap that in a function:

```
public function getUSer()
{
    $getCookieData = $this->Cookie->read('data');
    $getUser = $this->User->find('first', array('conditions' => array('User.username' => $getCookieData['username']))); 
    return $getUser;
}
```

And call it like `$this->getUSer()`. You should put that in class in context of your current value of `$this` eg in class where these functions are present.

You can also make it `static` (eg `public static function getUSer(){...}`) in which case you would be able to call it directly using `className::getUSer()` syntax.

Comment: Should i put this function in the AppController?

Comment: @SamPerrin: Yes you are right. Basically you should put it in in controller based on your needs. If you use that on multiple pages, you should put it in app level controller or if at specific place only then put in that controller only